# int.Parse Fails On Valid String

Tags: c#, parsing, int

I am completely lost with this.

So, I'm trying to use `int.TryParse` to parse a string, a perfectly valid string containing literally the number "3", that's it. But, it's giving me back false when I try to parse it.

This is how I'm using it - I've debugged it, and `int.TryParse` is definitely giving back false, as the code in the if statement runs:

```
if (!int.TryParse(numberSplitParts[0], out int hour))
        return false;
```

And I've looked in the debugger `numberSplitParts[0]` is definitely the digit 3, that's perfectly valid!
[image: Valid String In Debugger]

Now, I did some research and people have been saying to use the invariant CultureInfo, so, I did that, here's the new updated line (I also tried `NumberStyles.Any` and that didn't work either):

```
 if (!int.TryParse(numberSplitParts[0], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out int hour))
        return false;
```

That also doesn't work - it continues to give me back `false`, and `hour` is `0`.

I've tried all of the other number types as well - `byte.Parse`, `Int16.Parse` etc. All of those gave back `false` too.

And, I've tried regular `int.Parse`, and that simply gives me the following exception:

> **System.FormatException**: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

But then, I tried it in a different project, so, I replicated the string array and everything, *and it worked there* - both with and without "InvariantCulture".

So, I'm suspecting that the project I'm working in must be configured in such a way that caused `int.Parse`/`int.TryParse` to not work. This is in a class library, that is being accessed from a **UWP Application** - could the fact that this is running under UWP have any effect?

Comment: What happens if you put `numberSplitParts[0] == "3"` in the watch window? Let's make absolutely sure it's the string `"3"`, with no surprise unicode characters, etc.

Comment: @canton7 Ah! Now, that's interesting... It's giving me `false`... So, it's somehow a unicode character?

And, to confirm it, I copied out the number Visual Studio was giving me into Notepad++, alongside a normal typed "3", and the normal "3" was the HEX 33 - but the "3" that was in my variable was HEX 33E2808E

Comment: `e2 80 8e` is the UTF-8 sequence for [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm). That's managed to sneak into your string somehow

Comment: @canton7 Right! I'm seeing something here: I just went ahead and converted the string to a character array - and there were THREE characters in there - there was a quote, the number 3 and a quote... So, for whatever reason the number has quotes around it?

Comment: That's odd, and not consistent with any other information you've given . How did you convert the string to a character array exactly?

Comment: @canton7 I just ran `ToCharArray` on the string, it's weird that those quotes weren't showing in the debugger, but, they are definitely there... I tested `ToCharArray` in the other project that worked and there were no quotes, so, clearly something is wrong there. They seem to be a unicode character, since they're character number 8206...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205790/discussion-between-canton7-and-abperson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is due to a couple of [LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) Unicode characters in your input.

When you did your test in a different project, you probably hard-coded the string `"3"`, or got your input from a source which didn't add the same invisible characters.

A better test is to check whether `numberSplitParts[0] == "3"`, either in the watch window or in your code itself. Another is to set `numberSplitParts[0] = "3"` in your UWP project, and see if that parses correctly.

In my experience, most cases of "this string looks fine but <stuff> fails" is due to invisible Unicode characters sneaking into your input.